# Mailchimp API PHP - Assign subscriber to group based on html dropdown list

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

Using the Mailchimp API PHP example, I'm trying to pass a specific list group based on a drop-down menu value. I keep getting an error that $groupsval isn't a valid Interest Group. Eventually I'd set this up with some elseif statements for the other group options, but can't get this basic conditional working. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
   $groups = $_POST['listgroup']; //get listgroup form value, set as $groups var.

   if($groups == "broccoli") { // if it's broccoli, declare it a vegetable

      $groupsval = "vegetables";

     }

   $merge_vars = Array(
    'EMAIL' => $_GET['email'],
    'FNAME' => $_GET['fname'],
    'LNAME' => $_GET['lname'],
    'GROUPINGS'=>array(
        array('name'=>'Food', 'groups'=>'$groupsval'),
        )
    );
```

Comment: mailchimp has great support, so ask them.

Comment: The API error is less concerning, I'm just trying to figure out if the PHP syntax and logic is correct, or at least heading in the right direction.

Comment: not sure the real question then, basic debugging, echo the variables ans if they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Good point, $groupsval needed double quotes

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the single quotes on the right side of the =>  from `'groups'=>'$groupsval'` to just be `'groups' => $groupsval`

PHP does not process variables inside of single quotes.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is really old but just in case somebody needs it, there are 2 things to fix here:
1- As jeff pointed out you need to delete the quotation marks around $groupsval
2- $groupsval actually needs to be an array $groupsval = array("vegetables"). That's just in case you want them in more then 1 group